# Angular4: HttpClient - many requests in succession

Tags: angular, httprequest

I have a http get request to get a list of some items from a feed.
the feed API requires a page param, which is limited to 20. I would like to get first 60 instead, so I need to make 3 requests

```js
requestOptions.params.set('page', 1);
this.http.get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', requestOptions)
requestOptions.params.set('page', 2);
this.http.get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', requestOptions)
requestOptions.params.set('page', 3);
this.http.get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', requestOptions)
```

what is the best way to deal with it to get an ordered list? I am not very fond of nesting

Comment: You can use RxJs `flatmap` operator

Comment: when i need to send many request i use Observable.forkjoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your service:**

```
getPage(page) {
  /*init requestOptions*/
  requestOptions.params.set('page', page);
  return this.http
     .get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', requestOptions)
     .map(/*map your object to the expected one*/)
     .catch(/*catch any http exception*/);
}
```

**Somewhere where you call the service**

```
let allPages = [];

Observable.forkJoin(
  this.service.getPage(1);
  this.service.getPage(2);
  this.service.getPage(3);
).subscribe((respArray) =>{
   allPages = allPages.concat(respArray[0]);
   allPages = allPages.concat(respArray[1]);
   allPages = allPages.concat(respArray[2]);
});
```

`Object.forkJoin` will wait until all requests are completed and then you can build a single list with this results;

Comment: are they going to be executed in succession or are they ran simultaneously and you cannot rely on the results order? - oh, never mind... see you get separate responses as well... COOL, thanks

Comment: The result order is the calling order from the forkJoin: resp[0] should be the request for page 1, and etc

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this. I normally use `Observable.forkjoin or Observable.merge`

you can do this in below ways. Adjust the code little to run

```
// white a method which will call and get data and return observable
getData(pageNumber, requestOptions, environment) {
  requestOptions.params.set('page', pageNumber);
  return this.http.get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', requestOptions)
}

// make a fork-join/merge of all the observable and append the results

Observable.forkJoin(
   getData(pageNumber, requestOptions, environment);
   getData(pageNumber, requestOptions, environment);
   getData(pageNumber, requestOptions, environment);
).subscribe( (steream) => {
  //put some condition and all all those data
  result.push(stream);
});
```